# Jquery append element to Div and show/hide on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, append, element, show-hide

I am attempting to use Jquery to append a footer div into another div and have the newly appended footer div display on hover and slowly fade/hide afterwards. This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.xg_widget_main .module_forum .vcard').hover(function(){
$(this).append($('.module_forum .xg_module_foot').show('slow'));
});
</script>
```

The obstacle I am facing with this code is that the appended div will not obey the .show('slow') function and after the mouse is removed from the hover area the appended div does not fade out slowly, but instantly. Can someone kindly advise what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your HTML, and, if you can, please [post a live demo we can work with](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have now is that the result of `.append()` is your original element, not the new one you just appended.Try:

1. reversing the sense of your `append` logic
2. start the element off hidden:

e.g.

```
$('.module_forum .xg_module_foot').hide().appendTo(this).show('slow');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I wasn't getting something. It works perfect. How do get the appended div to disappear slowly using your recommendation?

Comment: The appended div doesnt disappear/fade out like I want it to when the mouse stops hovering over "xg_widget_main .module_forum .vcard", can you suggest how I can accomplish this?

Comment: @Allareone supply a second callback to `.hover()` with something like `$('.module_forum .xg_module_foot', this).hide('slow');`